# Configuring a self hosted GitLab-CE CI/CD server in parallel with a GitHub Team account

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, gitlab-ci, mesos

I am looking to perform code reviews as part of a trunk based development approach with my backend team on a self hosted gitlab server. I also wish to use it to deploy to internally hosted infrastructure. I also want to maintain my current Github team account from which I will be looking to make deployments to AWS and have it server as a backup of the main branch.

My approach to setting this up will be as follows:

- Create a new GitLab repository and initialize it with a README file.
- Set up a branch protection rule for my main branch (either called
  "main" or "master") to prevent direct pushes to it. I'll need to set
  up a rule to require code review and at least one approval from a
  team member before any changes can be merged.
- Create feature branches for new changes or bug fixes. These branches
  should be short-lived and should only contain the changes required
  for the specific task.
- Use merge requests (MRs) to merge changes from feature branches into
  the main branch. Each MR should have a description explaining the
  changes, and it should only include the changes required for the
  specific feature or bug fix.
- Use GitLab's code review features, such as inline comments and code
  snippets, to review and discuss changes with team members before
  merging them into the main branch.
- Set up automated testing and continuous integration (CI) using GitLab
  CI/CD to ensure that any changes merged into the main branch are
  automatically built, tested, and deploys an Apache Mesos cluster on my internal
  hardware.

In parallel to this last step I wish to mirror merges to my main branch to github but to selectively choose when I run Github Actions to deploy to an M3s / Apache mesos cluster to AWS.

Is this possible and does it abide by a sound trunk based development and CI/ CD methodology ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why you're using both GitHub and GitLab for the same project? Will developers be committing changes exclusively to GitLab or can changes be introduced on both either GitHub or GitLab? Is it actually important the code is viewable in GitHub, or do you only care about using GitHub Actions for the deployments? Are there important network boundaries between GitHub and GitLab, (is your GitLab server accessible from GitHub actions runners?). Also, git mirrors are NOT backups. You need a backup strategy your GitLab server storage.

Comment: I am using both because I was caught off guard with respect to hiring decisions and needed to give the developers a place to commit their code on day zero. I also had fears AWS might not play nicely with my self hosted GitLab CE instance. I know only too well from experience that I need a GitLab backup strategy (hence GitHub). Ideally I'd migrate to a paid version of GitLab instead of GitHub and have it deploy to both my internally hosted infrastructure as well as AWS but at 4 times the cost per user this seems a compromise of sorts. My interest really lies with GitLab Runners as a CI/CD tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds ok, though have some thoughts:

- CI you mentioned will also be running before merge, right? Hard to tell from the way you have formatted this.
- Why complicate this setup with both GitHub and GitLab?

  - both of them have very similar features. Especially GH can use self-hosted runners to deploy on-prem, and I'm guessing GL can deploy to AWS as well.
- don't mirror just the merges, mirror the whole main branch. Otherwise you can run into some weird issues down the path.

Comment: Thank you for seeking clarification, yes, CI will be running before merge. The reason for using both is firstly as an insurance policy, my current location is politically volatile and I would like to avoid downtime if I have to leave at short notice. (In which case your advice to mirror the whole main branch makes sense) Secondly I once encountered a little difficulty configuring AWS Amplify with a previously self hosted Gitlab instance and am a little wary of it not playing as nice as it might with a Github team instance.